# How to make multiple tags system for blogs?

Tags: php, mysql

I have my database setup like this:

```
posts
    post_id; primary_key
    title;
    content;
    date;
tags
    tag_id; primary_key
    post_id;
    tag_name;
```

In this blog, I'm letting users post their own tags, like YouTube.
So lets say, I'm letting the users type the tags in an input box.
For example, user types:
Cat Dog Food.

I want PHP to convert the input into an array and store it in the data base like this.

```
tags

    tag_id | post_id | tag_name
        1       1       Cat
        2       1       Dog
        3       1       Food
```

I think we can convert that string into an array using explode().
However, how do I structure my query to store into the database the way I want?

I basically want PHP to break each tag down, and store each tag in a separate row.

I'm using the while loop to pull each tags into the post btw.

Comment: Run your insert query within a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `foreach` loop. ie

```
$string= "cat,lion";
$array= explode(",",$string);
foreach($array as $tag)
{
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags(tag_id,post_id,tag_name) VALUES('','$post_id','$tag')"); // run query to insert into tags table. $post_id is the corresponding post_id you have.
}
```

Comment: and i think u made mistake in the foreach statement. $array is not defined. So it should be like foreach($tag as $tags). However, even after changing mine, its not inserting anything in the table.

Comment: Thanks for notifying the error. It was a typo. Any way, I checked it and output was fine. You just output the `query- INSERT INTO` and see whats you are getting.

Comment: Thanks, I had a mistake on my part as well. I didn't close my query, lol. Just realized it. Again, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Well have a different `tags` table to store your tags. It'd basically have 2 columns - `tag_id | tag_name`. Then have a table called `post_tags` with `post_id | tag_id` with a composite primary key on both the columns.

You can then just break the tags on comma (rather than spaces, so that tags can have spaces if you want), using `explode()` and `foreach` over the array to store them in the `tags` table first and then in the `post_tags` table.

You can have unique index on `tag_name` in `tags` table to prevent duplicate tag, and the primary composite index in `post_tags` table will prevent any duplicate `post_id | tag_id` rows anyway.